# Error when activating feature that installs a timer job

Tags: feature, timer-jobs

I have the following error when activating a feature, this feature is supposed to install a timer job.

> Failed to create receiver object from assembly "MundoNetElements,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9922d1e7c40d98f8",
>   class
>   "MundoNetElements.Features.NotificacionesContratosJob.NotificacionesContratosJobEventReceiver"
>   for feature "MundoNetElements_NotificacionesContratosJob" (ID:
>   33578802-a775-4777-9317-518bcdaceb06).: System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: type     at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()

This is my code,which doesnt have anything special and used several sample codes from other websites.

.feature

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feature xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core" dslVersion="1.0.0.0" Id="e67975ff-4d4f-4f6a-9349-e46cc0398745" alwaysForceInstall="true" description="This job executes periodically the notification process and the cleaning for the Mundo Net application" featureId="e67975ff-4d4f-4f6a-9349-e46cc0398745" imageUrl="" receiverAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" receiverClass="$SharePoint.Type.5de345c1-6a4c-48d8-8a8f-f80c531b438a.FullName$" scope="Site" solutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" title="MundoNetJob" version="" deploymentPath="$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/SharePointTools/FeatureModel" />
```

template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

Event Receiver

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;

namespace MundoNetElements.Features.MundoNetJob
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Esta clase controla los eventos generados durante la activación, desactivación, instalación, desinstalación y actualización de características.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// El GUID asociado a esta clase se puede usar durante el empaquetado y no se debe modificar.
    /// </remarks>

    [Guid("5de345c1-6a4c-48d8-8a8f-f80c531b438a")]
    public class MundoNetJobEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        const string List_JOB_NAME = "MundoNetJob";

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
            {
                if (job.Name == List_JOB_NAME)
                    job.Delete();
            }

            // install the job
            MundoNetElements.MundoNetJob listLoggerJob = new MundoNetElements.MundoNetJob(List_JOB_NAME, site.WebApplication);
            SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
            schedule.BeginHour = 23;
            schedule.BeginMinute = 0;
            schedule.BeginSecond = 0;                        
            schedule.EndHour = 23;
            schedule.EndMinute = 15;
            schedule.EndSecond = 0;
            listLoggerJob.Schedule = schedule;
            listLoggerJob.Update();
        }

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
            {
                if (job.Name == List_JOB_NAME)
                    job.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the timer job

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace MundoNetElements
{
    public class MundoNetJob : SPJobDefinition
    {
        public MundoNetJob() : base()
        {

        }

        public MundoNetJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType) : base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {

        }

        public MundoNetJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication) : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        { 
            this.Title = "Mundo Net job"; 
        }

        public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {
            // get a reference to the current site collection's content database

            //SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

            //SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];

            //// get a reference to the "ListTimerJob" list in the RootWeb of the first site collection in the content database

            //SPList Listjob = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["ListTimerJob"];

            //// create a new list Item, set the Title to the current day/time, and update the item

            //SPListItem newList = Listjob.Items.Add();

            //newList["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //newList.Update();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try restarting the timer service. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55217486-0df5-43ca-9487-cdb7a66334c9/powershell-installspsolution-failed-on-one-server-in-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: which scope does this feature have?

Comment: Restarting de timer service does not work @uberz91

Comment: @Gwny the scope is WebApplication

Comment: is it possible for you to debug with visualstudio while activating the feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your mistake is that `SPSite` is not the `properties.Feature.Parent` when your Feature has Scope `Webapplication`. Try this instead:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions){
           if (job.Name == List_JOB_NAME)
                   job.Delete();
}
```